# URL after hosting web application on cloud

Tags: python-2.7, cloud, google-cloud-platform

I was playing with google cloud just for the sake of learning cloud and web applications.
I made an application using 
1)Front end (html,CSS, javascript)
2)Database( sqlite)
3)Middleware(Python Flask)

I have the application running on my local system .I have a flask service running to collect and write data to my DB, an API interface(using flask) to read from the DB and the web application that uses this API to display graphs.
Now I want to host this in google cloud. If i do that I will have the web application running on a port. But will i be able to access that from outside. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Maybe this doc is related: [Testing and Deploying your Application](http://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/testing-and-deploying-your-app#deploying_your_application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's definitely possible, looks like you should give [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/) a try